# SQL paging a query that has a group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, pagination

Is it possible to do a paging type of query where my main query has a `group by` clause in it.

How would I implement this (if this is even possible)

Example query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,DATE), DATEPART(YEAR,MONTH)
```

Can I possibly get the result via reading it page by page?

...and while on the topic, can I also get the total number of rows that would be retrieved without putting it inside a sub query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` & CTE feature of SQL Server as mentioned below.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT     A,B,C
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  columnName) RN
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN Between 1 and 10
```

Please refer http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql/pagination-using-rownumber  for more details.

Answer (score -1):

The concept of pagination is :

1. You need to get the total number of rows.

   SELECT * FROM table_name where id='id';
2. Set the number of items to be show per page. Like $limit=50. This mean, you will show 50 items per page.

Hmm, I think it should be better if you'll take a look at this one, http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_pagination.htm. It's explained much more better.

Hope that helps.